# return a Json clickable list, from .netcore

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

net core development.
I'm trying to get a click-able list in a Json result
It seams **[AllowJsonGet]** is no longer possible in .net core,
So i try my way around it to code such a result.
The problem might be in my model definition or in my controller.
Maybe http urls should not be strings? (but then what should they be?)
Or should i add some extra verbs to Return Json(Clicklist) so that it knows of click-able urls ?

```
namespace Count.Models
{
  public class ReadItems
  {
    public string filename;
    public string url;
  }
}
```

In count.Controllers.cs i wrote:

```
namespace Count.Controllers
{

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    const string LogFolder = @"C:\Data\Count";
    String[] result = Directory.GetFiles(LogFolder);

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    //  [AllowJsonGet] Dissalowed in .net core 2.0

    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        List<Count.Models.ReadItems> clicklist = new List<Models.ReadItems>();
        List<string> allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(LogFolder).ToList();
        allFiles.Reverse(); //newest on top
        Models.ReadItems temp;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string File in allFiles)
        {
            temp = new Models.ReadItems();
            temp.filename = File.Replace(LogFolder + @"\\", ""); // remove real path
            temp.url = "../../Api/values/" + i.ToString();  // <==not working
            clicklist.Add(temp );
            i++;
        }
        return Json(clicklist);
}
```

Comment: What kind of json this generates and what do you expect it to generate?

Comment: "It seams [AllowJsonGet] is no longer possible in .net core" it's no longer possible because it's not needed, not it's allowed by default

Comment: @MiklósTóth It generates list based upon filenames, i can allready open a specific indexed item if i type the url in web brouwser manually, the link to that item (http://../../Api/Values/+index ) should be provided.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto [AllowJsonGet] has some security issues and therefor it was disables by Microsoft, typing in [AllowJsonGet] is not recognized anymore, is was allowed in .netcore 1.0 (or so) but starting from 2 it got disabled, as far as i have red today.